# Why I am getting Permission denied after executing this code?

Tags: python

I am trying to develop a code where I could restart a python script at a particular time as raspberry Pi is a host server. But after executing this code it is showing permission denied. What could be the possible reason.

```
import time
import sys
import os
from datetime import datetime


while True:

   now = datetime.now().time()
   print (now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), end = "", flush=True),
   print("\r", end ='', flush= True),
   time.sleep(1)

   if now.hour == 13 and now.minute == 43 and now.second ==00:
      os.execv("/home/pi/Desktop/rasp_2016/dummy_code.py", sys.argv) 
      exit
```

Comment: `/home/pi/Desktop/rasp_2016/dummy_code.py` is not marked as executable. You'll need to `chmod +x ` it

Comment: Do I need to add chmod +x  to the same path ("/home/pi/Desktop/rasp_2016/dummy_code.py") because after adding  ("/home/pi/Desktop/rasp_2016/chmod +x dummy_code.py") compiler is given an error which is no such file or directory.

Comment: https://www.washington.edu/computing/unix/permissions.html